# Creating a network packet without using Socket class

Tags: java, sockets, networking, packets

I am trying to encode/decode a network packet combining the sender IP address, destination IP address, sender port, destination port and payload data all together.

I've been reading the different ways to do this and everywhere suggests using the `Socket` class - however, we can't use real network classes like this in our program because it's just a simulated application with no real networking components.

I'm confused on how else I would create a network packet WITHOUT using classes like `DatagramPacket` or `DatagramSocket`. The payload data is in `byte[]` form and the IP addresses are `InetAddress`. I'm assuming I might have to use some kind of `ByteArrayOutputStream` to combine all these elements into one network packet of type `byte[]`.

Any suggestions for how I could do this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sockets are handled through the OS I believe. The java libraries just interface with the OS. I don't even think windows allows raw packet access. That is to say, there are some packets it won't even let you send

Comment: If the data goes nowhere surely you want to just store it in a `byte[]` and be done with it?

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do, but I am confused as to how I would combine the sending/recieving IP address, the sending/recieving port number, and the payload in byte[] all in one byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is confusing.  You are creating a networked application but you will never put your application on a network?  That makes no sense to me.

In Java the SocketFactory creates Sockets (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html).  You could implement your own SocketFactory to produce custom subclasses of Socket to create all the non-networky Socket things you need.  Without an actual network layer, though, I have no idea how you would get these non-network Sockets to communicate so that you can test stuff like "did the server receive the packet I sent".

Further, I don't think you need an actual Network to do Socket stuff.  localhost loopback serves this purpose.

I guess I'm just confused by your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I'm doing a bad job of explaining my question. The program is a simulation of a computer network. There is a "Computer" object, a "Switch Port" object that represents a physical Ethernet port, etc. I basically need to send a message from one "Computer A" object to a "Computer B" object using this network packet that includes the above information.

Comment: So it sounds like Sockets are irrelevant here, you are being asked to come up with an abstraction that has a source address, a destination address, and a byte[] payload.  Forget about Sockets and build that.  Thats, what, 2 classes; Address( String hostname, int port ) and Packet( Address source, Address destination, byte[] payload).  My advice, don't make this harder than it is.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just want to create/edit a byte[] or read a byte[]

because a datagram-packet is nothing else than a byte[]!!!

you might think of methods like:

```
byte[] package; //it sould be at least 20 byte and conform to TCP/IP IPv4

public static byte[] getSourceIp(byte[] package){
    byte[] sourceIp = new byte[4];
    //System.arraycopy(package, 96, sourceIp, 4); //way shorter
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
        sourceIp [i] = package[i+12]; //12=offset for source ip @ipv4
    }
    return sourceIp;
}

public static void setSourceIp(byte[] sourceIp , byte[] package){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
        package[i+12] = sourceIp[i];  //12=offset for source ip @ipv4
    }
}
```

let's assert you byte[] package is conform to the TCP/IP IPv4 protocol and at least 160 bit (20byte) long... 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4

Answer (score -1):

You can use DatagramPacket. It doesn't do anything to the network.

But it seems to me you should be rolling your own packet class here.

Comment: It's just a simulation program. OP seems to say that they can't use `DatagramPacket`.

Comment: Even if there's no real connection to outside world, simulation could be run pointing to self.

Comment: The instructions are a little ambiguous and just says that I can't use any "real" network classes of Java. I know this includes the Socket class but perhaps not the DatagramPacket class

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No. OP says there are 'no real network components'. He has *concluded,* incorrectly, that therefore he can't use DatagramPacket. I am correcting him. His own comment agrees.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but you should put all that, in detail, in the answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why should I put a correction of an incorrect statement by you that wasn't present when I posted my answer into my answer? What exactly is the comment system for?

Comment: @EJP I actually agree with your approach. Just adding that the fact there's no networking components doesn't refrain OP from creating packets and, if needed, connect to self.